# can be 'this' omitted when invoking method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, this, grammar, invoke

I have silly question about Java (6/7/8) grammar - are those two snippets of method invocation **always** equivalent?

1. with `this`

   ```
   this.myMethod(4);
   ```
2. without `this`

   ```
   myMethod(4);
   ```

**Note:** Of course the problem is about every number, type and combination of arguments

**Weaker statement:** given program `P`, can I create program `P'` only by deleting `this.` in front of each and every method invocation?

I've taken into account local classes, anonymous classes, inner classes and various inheritance but could have not find any contradiction. So i believe both snippets are actually the same. Unfortunately I can't manage to find any suitable proof (e.g. from the official grammar).

Could you prove me wrong by contradiction or give me some clues for construction of the equivalence proof? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: the equivalence was proven wrong (see comments below) What about the **weaker statement**?

Comment: No, it can't be omitted, you are forgetting static imports.

Comment: Ok, so equivalence is out. And what about the weaker statement? Won't be statically imported methods masqueraded by local ones, so when I omit `this.` the same function is called?

Comment: Looking at your weaker statement, yes, you can create a program, but will it be valid and compilable? Think of cases wherein method signature is different between static and member methods.

Comment: Could that even happen? Assuming valid input code, of course, by process of deleting `this.` can't be types violated in any possible way, can they?

Comment: Yes, that can happen. Unless you can guarantee that the code doesn't have any static methods which have the same name as object methods, there is always a possibility of messing things up.

Comment: but the arguments don't change - I still don't understand. Could you please provide some contradiction (example)? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1) states

> - If the form is `MethodName` - that is, just an `Identifier` - then:
>
>   - Otherwise, let `T` be the enclosing type declaration of which the method is a member, and let n be an integer such that `T` is the n'th
>       lexically enclosing type declaration of the class whose declaration
>       immediately contains the method invocation. The target reference is
>       the n'th lexically enclosing instance of `this`.

and

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword `this` denotes a value
>   that is a reference to the object for which the instance method or
>   default method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being
>   constructed

and

> - If the form is `Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier` involved, then:
>
>   - Otherwise, the Primary expression is evaluated and the result is used as the target reference.

`Primary` here referring to `this.*`.

In both cases, the method is going to be resolved to the same method.
Given all this information, there's is no compilable program `P'` that can be created from a compilable program `P`.

Answer (score 2):

There's at least one case where they aren't equivalent. For example, this code

```
void doStuff(){}
void test(){
    Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            doStuff();
        }
    };
    r.run()
}
```

Is perfectly valid, while this

```
void doStuff(){}
void test(){
    Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            this.doStuff();
        }
    };
    r.run()
}
```

isn't.

So if you have a method defined on a class, an anonymous object declared within that class can call it's methods without using `this`, but if it uses `this` it results in a compiler error (assuming it doesn't provide an implementation of the method name itself).

Comment: Fair enough. Given your second code, I could delete `this.` and get the first one (my second question aka Weaker statement). Would that always work?